# Why are the buttons in my react app overflowing the edge of the div?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm learning to develop and one of the sample projects I am attempting is a calculator. The calculator itself is working fine, but the buttons are overflowing the container and spill out over the edge of the calculator. CSS isn't my speciality and most of the things I can think of to make them fit as I want haven't worked. For reference, I want a square grid the fits symmetrically into the container, as an actual calculator looks. This is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#330e62, #0a080f);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 50px;
  color: #69f0ae;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 50px;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 40px;
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #69f0ae;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  text-align: right;
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #000000 0%, #414141 74%);
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2.5px 1.25px #00e676, 0 0 3px 1.5px #7cb342, 0 0 3.25px 2.5px #33691e;
  border: 4px solid #69f0ae;
}

.calculator {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #4a148c;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px #00e676, 0 0 25px 15px #81c784, 0 0 30px 22.5px #2e7d32;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #69f0ae;
}

.darkerpurple {
  background-color: #330e62;
  border-style: 4px solid;
  border-color: #69f0ae;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #00e676, 0 0 5px 3px #81c784, 0 0 6px 4px #2e7d32;
  color: #69f0ae;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 75px;
  color: #69f0ae;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 75px;
}

.lighterpurple {
  background-color: #4a148c;
  border-style: 4px solid;
  border-color: #69f0ae;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 2px #00e676, 0 0 5px 3px #81c784, 0 0 6px 4px #2e7d32;
  color: #69f0ae;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 1 1 calc(25% - 4px);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  width: 75px;
  font-size: xx-large;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  color: #69f0ae;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 75px;
}

.numbers-container {
  width: 75%;
}

.operations-container {
  width: 25%;
}

.darkerpurplereset {
  margin-right: 50%
}
```

```html
<div>HTML update place here please:


  export default class CalculatorButtons extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
      <div className="module-border-wrap">
          <div className="calculator">
              <div id="display" className="display">
                  {this.props.formulaEntered} <br/> {this.props.currentValue}
              </div>
              <div className="numbers-container">
                  <button className="darkerpuplereset">Reset</button>
                  {numbers.map(num => (
                      <CalculatorButton className={`darkerpurple ${num === 0 && 'big-h'}`} key={num} keyPressed={num} />
                  ))}
              </div>
              <div className="operations-container">
                  {operations.map(op => (
                    <CalculatorButton className="lighterpurple" key={op} keyPressed={op}/>
                  ))}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }

</div>
```

Sorry that this is difficult to read. the display is the screen for the calculator, the darker purple and lighter purple are both button classes (one for numbers and one for operations).

If anyone has any suggestions so that the buttons all fit nicely into the container that would be an amazing help, thank you :)

Comment: show the rendered HTML also to best allow us to help

Comment: NOT just a screen shot please since we cannot read that as HTML "code"

Comment: Okay I added the HTML snippet thanks for reminding me

Comment: Just a suggestion, I would remove all the react from this and put the HMTL that it renders in here so you can separate the behavior of the react code from the visual elements that are in place which requires the CSS.  More people will be able to answer quickly with viable answers if they do not have to make the react work here.